# How to combine livedata and kotlin flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

Is this good to put the collect latest inside observe?

```
viewModel.fetchUserProfileLocal(PreferencesManager(requireContext()).userName!!)
            .observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                if (it != null) {
                    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
                        viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                            launch {
                                viewModel.referralDetailsResponse.collect { referralResponseState ->
                                    when (referralResponseState) {
                                        State.Empty -> {
                                        }
                                        is State.Failed -> {
                                            Timber.e("${referralResponseState.message}")
                                        }
                                        State.Loading -> {
                                            Timber.i("LOADING")
                                        }
                                        is State.Success<*> -> {
                                            // ACCESS LIVEDATA RESULT HERE??
}}}}
```

I'm sure it isn't, my API is called thrice too as the local DB changes, what is the right way to do this?

My ViewModel looks like this where I'm getting user information from local Room DB and referral details response is the API response

```
private val _referralDetailsResponse = Channel<State>(Channel.BUFFERED)
val referralDetailsResponse = _referralDetailsResponse.receiveAsFlow()

init {
        val inviteSlug: String? = savedStateHandle["inviteSlug"]
        // Fire invite link
        if (inviteSlug != null) {
            referralDetail(inviteSlug)
        }
    }

fun referralDetail(referral: String?) = viewModelScope.launch {
        _referralDetailsResponse.send(State.Loading)
        when (
            val response =
                groupsRepositoryImpl.referralDetails(referral)
        ) {
            is ResultWrapper.GenericError -> {
                _referralDetailsResponse.send(State.Failed(response.error?.error))
            }
            ResultWrapper.NetworkError -> {
                _referralDetailsResponse.send(State.Failed("Network Error"))
            }
            is ResultWrapper.Success<*> -> {
                _referralDetailsResponse.send(State.Success(response.value))
            }
        }
    }

fun fetchUserProfileLocal(username: String) =
        userRepository.getUserLocal(username).asLiveData()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can combine both streams of data into one stream and use their results. For example we can convert `LiveData` to `Flow`, using [`LiveData.asFlow()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#asflow) extension function, and [`combine`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html) both flows:

```
combine(
  viewModel.fetchUserProfileLocal(PreferencesManager(requireContext()).userName!!).asFlow(),
  viewModel.referralDetailsResponse
) { userProfile, referralResponseState  ->
  ...
}.launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)
```

But it is better to move combining logic to `ViewModel` class and observe the overall result.

Dependency to use `LiveData.asFlow()` extension function:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, referralResponseState only gets a result when the API is called, i.e user opened app via referral link, the combine function didn't seem to execute. I've updated my question with how my VM and fragment looks.

Comment: Is there an example to move combining logic to `ViewModel`?

Comment: I believe logic is the similar: `combine(
  fetchUserProfileLoc..,
  referralDetailsResponse
) { ...  ->
  ... // use some state object, e.g. StateFlow, to notify UI
}.launchIn(viewModelScope)`

Answer (score 0):

it certainly is not a good practice to put a collect inside the observe.

I think what you should do is collect your livedata/flows inside your viewmodel and expose the 'state' of your UI from it with different values or a combined state object using either Flows or Livedata

for example in your first code block I would change it like this

- get rid of "userProfile" from your viewmodel
- create and expose from your viewmodel to your activity three LiveData/StateFlow objects for your communityFeedPageData, errorMessage, refreshingState
- then in your viewmodel, where you would update the "userProfile" update the three new state objects instead

this way you will take the business logic of "what to do in each state" outside from your activity and inside your viewmodel, and your Activity's job will become to only update your UI based on values from your viewmodel

For the specific case of your errorMessage and because you want to show it only once and not re-show it on Activity rotation, consider exposing a hot flow like this:

```
private val errorMessageChannel = Channel<CharSequence>()
val errorMessageFlow = errorMessageChannel.receiveAsFlow()
```

What "receiveAsFlow()" does really nicely, is that something emitted to the channel will be collected by one collector only, so a new collector (eg if your activity recreates on a rotation) will not receive the message and your user will not see it again

Comment: where do I collect my `referralDetailsResponse`?

Comment: where does it come from? I see from your code it is inside the viewmodel. does it come from somewhere else or are you updating it inside the viewmodel? If I understand your code well enough, I would collect/observer fetchUserProfileLocal inside the viewmodel and then update the referralDetailsResponse accordingly. Then in your activity you would collect referralDetailsResponse directly and not within an observe

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question with code of the view model for better understanding

Comment: sorry for the late response, I haven't logged into this account for some time.

I would remove the _referralDetailsResponse and whereever you update that, I would instead update the 'communityFeedPageData', the 'errorMessage' and the 'refreshingState' I mention above